# Best approach for RDF output CMS

Tags: xml, drupal, content-management-system, joomla, rdf

Can anyone recommend a good CMS which will output PURE RDF documents (I don't just want HTML pages with RDF properties). I basically want to have a database containing some data and have the CMS format that into pure XML RDF documents.

I know Drupal has limited support but this seems to just add RDF attributes to HTML elements.

Anyone else have a better approach...?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any CMS that allows you to do this out of the box. CMS's are usually made to create webpages after all.

### Drupal

This can be done with Drupal, but it will require some work, depending on what type of XML RDF documents you need to generate, this can be a greater or lesser work load.

Since all markup is defined by theme functions and templates, all you need to do, is to overwrite the default ones. If all you want, is to create this special output for raw content - called nodes in Drupal - you would only need to create a customized node template, and a special page template, which creates the surrounding markup like doctypes etc.

If this is the case, you shouldn't need much extra work compared to a special design node, like products in a shopping site. The [context module](http://drupal.org/project/context) can help you managing which page template to use for different types of content/urls.

So with the modules available and Drupal's great flexibility, could be done without too much work. My guess is that Drupal would be the best choice, since for such a thing, flexibility is critical, the thing Drupal does better than all other CMS I've seen.

Comment: Excellent thanks, do you know if Drupal allows you to change the actual content type declaration, i.e. from text/html to txt/xml?

Comment: @Simon: There's an API function for it. For D6 it's `drupal_set_header`